# Avoiding vertical spaces between bibitems while using IEEEtran

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm using `IEEEtran` class and bibliography style and I see that the references section that it generates leaves empty lines between bibitems when the `compsocconf` option is used. Is there a way to avoid this?

Note: If you do not use the `compsocconf` option, which is meant for Computer Society conferences, you don't have this problem. Also, the article is a lot more compact as a whole.

Comment: Please consider to convert your "Note" to an answer to your own question (self-answers are permissible). Otherwise, your question is likely to remain part of the "Unanswered questions" list.

Comment: I thought it might be a good idea to keep the question open since it is not yet answered for the situation when one wants to use the `compsocconf` option.

Answer (score 6):

This behaviour is not specific to `ieeetran.bst`, but also occurs with, e.g., the `plain` style. LaTeX uses the `thebibliography` environment to typeset the "References" section. `thebibliography` in turn uses the generic `list` environment, and lists by default add vertical space between (bibliography) items. To remove the spacing, one must add `\itemsep 0pt` at the right place of the definition of `\thebibliography`. (In the following example, I use the etoolbox package to selectively change the definition.)

EDIT: As you didn't reveal your document class, I'm assuming a standard class here, or at least a class with a "standard" definition of the `thebibliography` environment.

EDIT 2: In response to your revised question: Here's how to use the `ieeetran` class with the options `compsoc` and `conference` (sic!), but without enlarged vertical space between bibitems.

```
\documentclass[compsoc,conference]{ieeetran}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\leftmargin\labelwidth}
%     {\itemsep 0pt \leftmargin\labelwidth}{}{}

\def\IEEEbibitemsep{0pt plus .5pt}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work for me. The algorithm2e package threw up an error that wasn't appearing earlier. When I ignored the error, the spaces between bibitems remained in the output. I'm using the IEEETran class file.

Comment: Using the `ieeetran` class, I get no spaces between bibitems from the outset, so you must be doing something else. Please provide a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: While trying to create the minimal example, I figured that when I dropped the "compsocconf" option of the IEEEtran class file, the spacing disappeared. This even without using the etoolbox package. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 3):

Please add the following command before `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}`:

```
\newcommand{\BIBdecl}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.25 em}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found a solution [here](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/spacing-between-entries-in-bibtex-generated-bib/1929386).

Add the following code to your preamble:

```
\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
   \begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{-.3ex}%
}%
{%
   \end{oldthebibliography}%
}
```

worked for me on `\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}`