# Using "normal" IEEEtran-bibliography in "compsocconf" document

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style

I currently use two different templates:

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, compsocconf]{IEEEtran}
```

and

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
```

I really like "compsocconf", but the bibliography style is not that great. Is it possible to use the first template with the bibliography style of the second template?

Thank you very much

-edit-

The specific problem is that the vertical space between the entries is too large. I like to reduce this space.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific about the aspects of the bibliography formatting you're not happy about.

Comment: I updated the question: The specific problem is that the vertical space between the entries is too large. I like to reduce this space.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code. - - Does [Avoiding vertical spaces between bibitems while using IEEEtran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25754/124842) help?